# How to send event.target through to mock a function using FormData

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to mock a function that uses `FormData`. The function accepts a param of event that relies on something being in the target.

```
  buildFormData: (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { target } = event;
    const data = new FormData(target);

    if (target.querySelectorAll('.ant-select').length) {
      const selectTags = target.querySelectorAll('.ant-select');

      selectTags.forEach((selectTag) => {
        const value = selectTag.querySelector('.ant-select-selection-selected-value').getAttribute('title');
        const property = selectTag.getAttribute('id');
        data.append(property, value);
      });
    }

    const getDataObject = {};

    for (var pair of data.entries()) {
      // Ensures that the data from the forms have a value
      if (pair[1]) {
        getDataObject[pair[0]] = pair[1];
      }
    }

    return getDataObject;
  }
```

I want to ensure that the function returns an object of values from a mocked form.

I've tried passing:

```
const event = {
  target: {}
}
```

but realized quickly that the target is empty.

Is there an easy way to mock this data so I get the expected return from my function above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution, you can mock `FormData` and form `event` manually:

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import console = require('console');

class XComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.buildFormData = this.buildFormData.bind(this);
  }
  public buildFormData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { target } = event;
    const data: any = new FormData(target);

    if (target.querySelectorAll('.ant-select').length) {
      const selectTags = target.querySelectorAll('.ant-select');

      selectTags.forEach(selectTag => {
        const value = selectTag.querySelector('.ant-select-selection-selected-value').getAttribute('title');
        const property = selectTag.getAttribute('id');
        data.append(property, value);
      });
    }

    const getDataObject = {};
    for (const pair of data.entries()) {
      // Ensures that the data from the forms have a value
      if (pair[1]) {
        getDataObject[pair[0]] = pair[1];
      }
    }

    return getDataObject;
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.buildFormData}></form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default XComponent;
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import XComponent from './';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

const FormDataMock = {
  append: jest.fn(),
  entries: jest.fn()
};

describe('XComponent', () => {
  const mockedFormEvent = { target: { querySelectorAll: jest.fn() }, preventDefault: jest.fn() };

  beforeEach(() => {
    (global as any).FormData = jest.fn(() => FormDataMock);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('should build form data correctly without select tags', () => {
    mockedFormEvent.target.querySelectorAll.mockReturnValueOnce([]);
    FormDataMock.entries.mockReturnValueOnce([['k1', 'v1'], ['k2', 'v2'], ['k3', 'v3']]);
    const wrapper = shallow(<XComponent></XComponent>);
    const actualValue = (wrapper.instance() as any).buildFormData(mockedFormEvent);
    expect(actualValue).toEqual({ k1: 'v1', k2: 'v2', k3: 'v3' });
    expect(mockedFormEvent.preventDefault).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockedFormEvent.target.querySelectorAll).toBeCalledWith('.ant-select');
    expect((global as any).FormData).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('should build form data correctly with select tags', () => {
    const mockedSelectTag = { querySelector: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), getAttribute: jest.fn() };
    const mockedSelectTags = [mockedSelectTag];
    (mockedSelectTag.querySelector().getAttribute as any).mockReturnValueOnce('value').mockReturnValueOnce('property');
    mockedFormEvent.target.querySelectorAll.mockReturnValue(mockedSelectTags);
    FormDataMock.entries.mockReturnValueOnce([['k1', 'v1'], ['k2', 'v2'], ['k3', 'v3']]);
    const wrapper = shallow(<XComponent></XComponent>);
    const actualValue = (wrapper.instance() as any).buildFormData(mockedFormEvent);
    expect((global as any).FormData).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(actualValue).toEqual({ k1: 'v1', k2: 'v2', k3: 'v3' });
    expect(FormDataMock.append).toBeCalledWith('property', 'value');
    expect(mockedFormEvent.preventDefault).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockedFormEvent.target.querySelectorAll).toBeCalledWith('.ant-select');
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58136380/index.spec.tsx (5.601s)
  XComponent
    ✓ should build form data correctly without select tags (11ms)
    ✓ should build form data correctly with select tags (3ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |    83.33 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |    83.33 |      100 |      100 |                27 |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.438s, estimated 15s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58136380

Comment: Is there a way to test just the function rather than expecting it to be in a component? Thanks for the answer this is really helping.

Comment: dw about the comment, Thanks for your answer. I've got it working now